# SelectList ToShortDateString viewbag

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

My project is MVC5, using EF 6.1; I generate dropdownlist using the following:

Model:

```
public partial class LogBook
{
    public string ID { get; set; }
    public string TheName { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Day { get; set; }
}
```

Controller:

```
var list = db.LogBook.Where(i => i.TheName == xxx).OrderByDescending(x => x.Day).ToList();
ViewBag.Logbooks = new SelectList(list, "ID", "Day");
```

View:

```
@Html.DropDownList("logbookdate", ViewBag.LogBooks  as SelectList)
```

The result shows:

```
11/11/2014 12:00 AM
```

How can I just display the date?

Comment: Initialize `List<SelectListItem>` and add instances of `SelectListItem` where you set `Value = ID.ToString()` and `Text = Day.ToShortDateString()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var list = db.LogBook.Where(i => i.TheName == xxx).Select(d=> new {ID= d.TheName, Day = d.Day.ToShortDateString()).OrderByDescending(x => x.Day).ToList();
 ViewBag.Logbooks = new SelectList(list, "ID", "Day");
```

Haven't done practical but should work.

Edit:

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList = 
    from c in db.LogBook
    where c.TheName equals xxx
    select new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = c.ID,
        Value = c.Day.ToShortDateString()
    };
```

Then bind it to dropdonwlist on front.

You can give it a try. I have not checked syntax. Hope its fine.

Comment: Thank you, I got this error:  LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var list = db.LogBook.Where(i => i.TheName == xxx).OrderByDescending(x => x.Day).ToList();
```

Change in query

```
IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectList = db.LogBook
                                           .Where(i => i.TheName == xxx)
                                           .Select(c => new SelectListItem
                                           {
                                              Text = c.ID,
                                              Value = c.Day.ToShortDateString()                                                
                                           });
```